# Print to log file without newline - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a logger to print to a file:

```
logger = Logger.new Rails.root.join 'log/my.log'
```

How can I print several dots in one line in different logger calls?

i.e., if I do

```
some_array.each do |el|
  logger.info '.'
  el.some_method
end
```

These dots will be printed in different lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-3C-3C) method lets you write messages without any formatting the log file.

For example:

```
require 'logger'

log = Logger.new "test.log"
log.info "Start"
5.times { log << "." }
log << "\n"
log.info "End"
```

Produces:

```
I, [2014-03-10T15:11:04.320495 #3410]  INFO -- : Start
.....
I, [2014-03-10T15:11:42.157131 #3410]  INFO -- : End
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't let you write to the same line as previous calls to `log.info`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Logger#<<(msg)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-3C-3C)

> Dump given message to the log device without any formatting. If no log
>   device exists, return nil.

```
some_array.each do |el|
  logger << '.'
  el.some_method
end
```

Answer (score 2):

And you can still keep it restricted by the logger.level by using `.info?`

```
some_array.each do |el|
  logger << '.' if logger.info?
  el.some_method
end
```

Comment: Nice! I will add a method to the logger with something like  `send('<<', c) if self.level >= level`